# CakePHP - Using User model in SecurityComponent

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a application based on REST requests and I'm using SecurityComponent for HTTP Authorisation. My question is - how can I use a User model with it? Instead of giving a array of usernames and passowrds...

Cheers,
Lucas

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?  I'm trying to do this too and could do with some help if you have any tips.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to copy file **app_controller.php** to /app folder
2. Try to add the line

   var $uses = array('User');

after

```
class AppController extends Controller
```

line

Comment: Yes, I know about that :) However it's not what meant... I want to be able to identify user (from my user model) based on login data from HTTP Authorization